# Android NDK: C++ struct member access, causes SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)

Tags: c++, struct, android-ndk, alignment, android-studio-2.3

I'm porting a C++ library on Android (Android Studio 2.3.1/NDK 25); the library works flawlessly on UWP (VS2017 VC 1.41 - ARM & Win32) a custom ARM7 board (GCC 4.8).

When debugging on Android Studio, I get a *"SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)"* during an assignment to a struct member.
Here is the struct (I need it to be 64-bit aligned):

```
typedef unsigned int        _t_u32;         // 32-bit unsigned
typedef unsigned long long  _t_u64;         // 64-bit unsigned

typedef struct __attribute__((aligned(8)))
{
    _t_u32      crc32;
    _t_u64      counter;

} t_security;
```

Now, here is the code snippet:

```
void prepareBuffer(_t_u8 cmd, _t_u8 *buffer, _t_u32 buffferLen)
{
    t_security *secPtr = ((t_security *)(buffer + sizeof(_t_u8)));

    secPtr->crc32 = 0;
    secPtr->counter= 0; << when this is being executed, on Android Studio-only, I get *"SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)"*
    ...
    ...
}
```

From Android Studio debugger watches:

```
sizeof(t_security) = {unsigned int} 16
&secPtr = {t_security * | 0xdc98eb41} 0xdc98eb41
&secPtr->crc32 = {_t_u32 * | 0xdc98eb41} 0xdc98eb41
&secPtr->counter = {_t_u64 * | 0xdc98eb49} 0xdc98eb49
```

From Visual Studio debugger watches (ARM platform):

```
sizeof(t_security)  16  unsigned int
secPtr  0x00afe2e5 {crc32=3435973836 ...}   t_security *
&secPtr->crc32  0x00afe2e5 {3435973836} unsigned int *
&secPtr->counter    0x00afe2ed {14757395258967641292}   unsigned __int64 *
```

I suppose it has to due to packing/member alignment... but as you can notice, the packaging seems consistent on the two platforms... just on Android Studio-only, I get *"SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)"*.

Can someone please help me understand what's going on? 
May be a compiler switch I'm missing? Here's the ndk's gradle config:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "NativeLib"

    // add compilation flags
    cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
    cppFlags.add("-frtti")
    cppFlags.add("-std=c++14")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")

    // include headers
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("native-src")}".toString())

    ldLibs.addAll("android", "dl", "log", "z", "atomic")

    stl = "c++_static"  // LLVM compiler
}
android.buildTypes {
    all {
        // To solve struct packing issues, setting abiFilters to package only 32-bit architectures:
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            abiFilters.add("mips")
            abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
    }
    debug {
        ndk.with {
            cppFlags.add("-DDEBUG")
            CFlags.add("-DDEBUG")
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste mistake. Isn't the last `counter` address `0x00efe26d`?

Comment: Apologies for that, I corrected with fresh data from another run. Thanks

Comment: I guess the other ARM platform handles unaligned access. ARM7 architecture allows this, but at rather high price. I strongly recommend to rewrite your code so that all data access is aligned.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I appreciate your suggestion. Although in the "tiny world" (ARM7), I can't afford memory allocation & communication with align-bloated memory chunks. I designed the ARM7 hw platform & a custom rtos, and can't see why ndk has such limitation (as VS & gcc don't)... there has to be some compiler switch or so... I hope :)

Comment: Here the CPU setup is described: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/CDFEJCBH.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue.

In your code snippet, `secPtr` is not aligned because it points to `buffer` offseted by 1(`sizeof(_t_u8)`) byte. (assuming that `buffer` is aligned address)

All 4-byte ailgned memory addresses should end in '0', '4', '8' or 'C'. Since `secPtr` ends in '5', it is not aligned.

ARM processors support some of unaligned memory access. That is why `secPtr->crc32 = 0;` is legal, but `secPtr->counter= 0;` is not.

Try removing 1-byte offset in `secPtr` somehow and see if the problem goes away.

Also check out this page for detailed information: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html

Comment: Hi gasbank, that is exactly the point, so marking yours as the answer.
Didn't had yet the chance to update the community (apologies for that), but I managed to "restructure" my data & code so that to carry over the full aligned pointer, rather than re-basing it for casting.
Thanks!

Comment: PS: just as an info, custom struct packing size on the default Android Studio compiler can be achieved with the `cppFlags.add("-fpack-struct=[no of bytes]")` , within the `android.ndk` section of the build gradle.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your's gtrevi. Funny enough that actually it's your question that helped me a lot to get ideas what's going wrong with mine. Thanks for sharing your issue with quite a detailed description. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer @gasbank, you helped me fixing the same issue on my project. I was allocating some extra bytes at the top of my buffers and using some neon instructions were causing a SIGBUS. I solved it by aligning the extra bytes however for me it was 8 bytes and not 4, not sure why.

Comment: Dead link. The [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200131152544/http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html) didn't help either.