# How do I fix an error in a header file typedef struct (expected a ";")?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I downloaded this project from github https://github.com/fabvalaaah/rlec and in bitmap.h there is an error in typedef struct (expected a ";"). In the rest of the project there is an error with _bitmap (identifier is undefined). I am using Visual studio 2019. How do I fix it?

```
#ifndef BITMAP_H
#define BITMAP_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "common.h"

const uint8_t lineFeed;
const uint8_t imageEnd;

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) _bitmap{ //Error is here on _bitmap
    uint8_t magicNumber[2];
    uint32_t size;
    uint8_t reserved[4];
    uint32_t startOffset;
    uint32_t headerSize;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t depth;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imageSize;
    uint32_t xPPM;
    uint32_t yPPM;
    uint32_t nUsedColors;
    uint32_t nImportantColors;
}
_bitmap;

void printHeader(_bitmap* image);
int RLECompression(FILE* ptrIn, FILE* ptrOut);
int RLEDecompression(FILE* ptrIn, FILE* ptrOut);

#endif /* BITMAP_H */
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so you can copy-paste (as text) the full and complete error you get into it. Also please add a comment in the shown code where you get the error. Also please tell us what compiler you're using, because the shown code includes some non-standard and non-portable extensions that might not work on your compiler.

Comment: And wouldn't it be better to try and create a [mcve] which you can use to possibly report the problem to the project author instead?

Comment: Which compiler? The attribute packed is a gcc only non-standard extension, which other compilers won't recognize. Also, you should never declare variables in header files, for multiple reasons.

Comment: I edited my question. I am using Visual studio 2019 and the error is in typedef struct.

Comment: There's your error. As mentioned the header file is using a non-standard and non-portable extension (the `__attribute__` thing), which is not available in all compilers. Most notable `__attribute__` is not supported by Visual Studio. The Visual C++ variant is [the pack pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019). You need to add some *conditional compilation* to choose which to use (and perhaps add a feature request to the project authors to add such).

Answer (score 1):

The code is using gcc extensions. So the easiest way to compile it would be to just use the gcc compiler.

But what you can do is changing

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) _bitmap{
```

to

```
typedef struct _bitmap{
```

It may work, and it may break the code depending on what happens in other parts of the code. My guess is that it will work perfectly fine, but I cannot guarantee that the author of the code have not done anything "clever".

Comment: @viribus If your problem has been solved, feel free to accept an answer.

Comment: @viribus Note that `pack` may be important to get the exact fields layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) _bitmap
```

This is the way to define a struct definition without zero paddings in GCC.
To prevent zero padding in MVSC, use `#pragma pack`:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct _bitmap{ //Error is here on _bitmap
    uint8_t magicNumber[2];
    uint32_t size;
    uint8_t reserved[4];
    uint32_t startOffset;
    uint32_t headerSize;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint16_t planes;
    uint16_t depth;
    uint32_t compression;
    uint32_t imageSize;
    uint32_t xPPM;
    uint32_t yPPM;
    uint32_t nUsedColors;
    uint32_t nImportantColors;
} _bitmap;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

As you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/Gr-Rsw it compiles just fine.

Note that disabling padding **is important** to get the exact structure you want (first 2 bytes which are "magic number" then 4 bytes of size, etc). In such case you can read first `sizeof(_bitmap)` bytes from the file and expect the layout be exactly as defined in the struct.

Without the `#pragma pack`, the size of such struct may very based on different architectures. For example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/pSQ53n) the size is 56 byte, that's because the compiler adds padding after `magicNumber[2]` to align it to 4 bytes while with the `pack` attribute it is 54 bytes ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/MvdXkm)).

Comment: When I see `__attribute__((__packed__))` or `#pragma pack(push,1)` I think, "Bad code.  Either too lazy or not given enough time to do proper, reliable, portable serialization.  What **else** is going to be done sloppily like that?"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Totally disagree with you. Packing usually required to comply with some standard protocol. Assume that the structure `_bitmap` is not defined by you but by the definition of the bitmap file header or hardware block. Leaving the structure without packing, may cause padding on some architectures when, for example, compiled for best performance (`-O3`). The compiler may locate each struct at offset aligned to 64 bits.

Comment: *Packing usually required to comply with some standard protocol.*  A "standard protocol" does not depend on platform-specific implementations such as packed structures.  Using packed structures to serialize to or deserialize from a standard protocol is lazy and makes me wonder what other shortcuts were taken.  If an implementation provides a packed structure, it's not portable and it's not standard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle on the contrary. Once you have a defined layout, either you copy field by field manually and fill in the fields of your structure (and such conversion should be done in both directs, on receiving and on sending the data) or you defines the structure without padding and then you can just `memcopy` it in any direction. I wouldn't call it *lazy*. Sometimes performance matters.

Comment: *you defines the structure without padding and then you can just `memcopy` it in any direction*  And you just missed having to deal with endianness, which every standard protocol will address.  You just made my point about bad code and making me wonder what **else** got missed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So you are saying that working with "flat" data buffers of bytes would be better? Have you tried to maintain such thing? each change/new field addition/removal will require a complicated code change in order not to break anything. Structs were introduced exactly for such thing.

Comment: So it's too hard to do things portably and reliably?  Every single argument you're making only reinforces my belief that using packed structures is the lazy, non-portable solution.  [It's not guaranteed to work, even on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790815/4756299).  If you can't update serialization/deserialization code to add something like a network-byte-order `uint32_t` to a protocol, you can't safely write C code anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The link you provided is irrelevant to packing. It is about breaking alignment. Packing is needed because sometimes (for example on 64bit architecture) even a struct with two ‘uint32_t’ fields may be padded to force each field be aligned to 64 bits due to performance issues.

Comment: *The link you provided is irrelevant to packing.* Again, you miss the point: *It is about breaking alignment.*  That's exactly what packing does - it breaks alignment.  [And causes failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559712/android-ndk-c-struct-member-access-causes-sigbus-signal-sigbus-illegal-ali).  The fact that you apparently don't know this just reinforces my opinion of the use of packed structures - it's a lazy way bad coders do serialization/deserialization and it's use immediately makes me wonder what else is wrong in the code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Anything that is done without thinking is a bad coding. I never said *force packing everywhere*. Each structure field requires minimal alignment requirement (based on its type). As long as those requirements take place, nothing bad will happen. For example struct with `{ uint32_t, uint16_t, uint16_t };` will satisfy the alignment requirements even after packing but packing, in this case, will ensure that the memory footprint (layout) of such struct is exactly as defined.